# Can we keep ## table that is created from .NET until i execute my code from another procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, temp-tables

I have a .NET application where I have to create a `##table` or physical table.

- Step 1: I read the data from `Server1` and call `db.ExecuteList` method
- Step 2: Create table on `Server2` and Populate the table  using `SqlBulkCopy` (Because of large volume of data)
- Step 3: After the table population, I call another procedure that is on `Server2` to populate the data on `Server2` tables. Here I have to read the data within this stored procedure
- Step 4: then drop the table.

If it is any physical table, the table is available until I call any stored procedure from .NET.

But instead of the physical table, if I create a `##table`, will that table be available until I call the next stored procedure?

Anyone come across this scenario?

Appreciate your responses.

Comment: Why do you want to use a ##table versus a physical table?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a "##Table", that table will stay in existence until the connection that created it is closed.   As long as you do all of your steps without closing the connection, the same ##Table will exist for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this short article will give you all the information you need (you can read only the first part which is about the temporary tables general concepts):
[Indexing SQL Server Temporary Tables](https://www.sqlshack.com/indexing-sql-server-temporary-tables/)

Comment: This would be a great comment but it's quite poor for an answer.

Comment: Earned the possibility to comment questions right after posting this answer